# assign product id to given options

Tags: product, configurable-product, custom-options

I am having a Product Id, which is a configurable product. For this product I am getting the options I can choose from like you can see below:

```
    $productAttributeOptions = $Product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($Product);
    $attributeOptions = array();
    foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
        foreach ($productAttribute['values'] as $attribute) {
            $attributeOptions[$productAttribute['label']][$attribute['value_index']] = $attribute['store_label'];
        }
    }
    $product['options'] = $attributeOptions;
```

With that code I get something like that:

[image: json format of the results of the code above]

But now I want to get the assigned product Id of the options. So I want to know the product Id if you choose the color "Grey" and size "M" for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like that :

```
$configurable= Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($product);
$simpleCollection = $configurable->getUsedProductCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
   ->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('eq'=>$color))
   ->addAttributeToFilter('size', array('eq'=>$size));
```

You should obtain a collection with a single product that correspond to you declination of the configurable.